# Our toddler boy likes to arrange his toy cars in a line. Is this normal?

Tags: toddler, behavior

Our 3-year-old son likes cars, and he likes to arrange his toy cars in a line. Is this normal for toddler boys?

Comment: If this is the most serious thing you have to worry about, ...

Comment: No, not really. Most kids aren't nearly that organized.

Comment: Isn't this how he sees real cars? Lined up in lanes, lined up parked on the side of the road . . . kid's got his eyes open is all.

Comment: My kid did this all the time when he was 1-year-old, and with everything. He was a real train aficionado then, so I guess he was building train sets. Now he's a pretty normal 5-year-old. If your son is not extremely obsessive, that's just a pattern he has picked up.

Comment: Data point, not answer:  My 2yo is going through a phase of lining up toys.  Cars, nesting blocks, Duplo bricks, basically anything they can readily move about.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I had a friend whose son did the exact same thing.  He played constantly with toy cars, and all he did was carefully line them up end-to-end.

I'm not sure if you had a specific concern, but I'd say it's not only "normal", but it's also fairly common.

Comment: Agree. Both my kids did this with cars.

Comment: Ditto.  And mine come from a long line of engineers on both sides, so we attribute it to being a sign that new geeks are forming. :)

Comment: Yep. Another +1 from here and the same comment as @Valkyrie

Comment: same - lots of lines of cars here :)

Comment: I have girls and they're the same.  Our 20 month old lined her little play people up just this morning and then brought it to my attention to show how clever she'd been.

Comment: very common. My toddler is very disorganized and he still does this from time to time.

Answer (score 8):

It's a fairly normal thing, I'd say. My daughter spends ages every night ensuring that all her cuddly toys are in exactly the right position. Some kids simply like things to be just so.

Comment: And then they grow up and tell their husbands to lower the toilet seats. Ugh;)

Comment: @Dariusz or they grow up and go from super organized must be perfect to "It's organized chaos, I swear!  I know exactly where everything is even though it looks like a tornado just passed through."   ... That wasn't me at all >_>

Comment: I knew exactly where everything was until you cleaned the room, damnit!

Answer (score 5):

Datapoint: mine do that too. It may be a symptom of toomanycaritis :)

Seems pretty normal to me.